# Continuous maps on smoth manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, continuity, manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^{\infty}$ map and $f(p)=0$.

**My question:**Does there exist a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ in $M$ such that $f(U)=0$?

i know by coordinate system $(V,x)$ of $M$, $f\circ x^{-1}: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $W:= (f\circ x^{-1})^{-1}{(0)}$ is closed (not open subset). Is there any theorem that can help me?

Comment: Think of ordinary funtion (that is, $M =\mathbb R$). Is it possible?

Comment: suppose $f$ be differentiable.

Comment: Is it possible if $f$ is differentiable? Can you think of a smooth function which is zero only at one point?

Comment: No, but how can i prove this?

Comment: What kinds of functions do you know?

Comment: I mean, can you provide an example of a nontrivial real valued smooth function $f : \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$?

Comment: in your opinion, there exists any open subset $U$ such that $f(U)=0$?

Comment: I didn't mean that. Question: Is this $f(x) = x$ a smooth functions on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: yes, it is smooth.

Comment: Now for this $f$, $f(0) =0$. Can you find an open neighborhood $U$ of $0$ so that $f(U) = 0$ ?

Answer (score 2):

If so, $f$ would be constant (on each connected component of $M$). To see this, assume that $M$ is connected, take some $p\in M$ and put $g := f - f(p)$. Then $g(p) = 0$. Hence, $g(x) = 0$ for all $x\in M$ in a neighborhood of $p$. Thus, $g$ is locally constant and so is $f$. But $f$ is continuous and therefore constant.